# Rails app not following the timezone configured in config/application.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, timezone, utc

I'm new to configuring timezones and confused about a few points. Any advice on the correct configuration would be appreciated.

My understanding is that it's best practice to store all timestamps as UTC in the DB (I'm using PostgreSQL). On the other hand, in the actual app, I'd like to see the timestamps in my local timezone (JST +9:00).
I've configured `config/application.rb` like this:

```rb
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.load_defaults 5.2
    config.time_zone = 'Tokyo'
  end
end
```

However, I'm not sure it's configured correctly, because I'm getting mixed results in the `rails console`. `Time.zone` and `Time.now` tell me the timezone is set to JST, but the `created_at` and `updated_at` timestamps are rendered as UTC when I do `User.first`.

```rb
User.first
#=> #<User id: 1, first_name: "Bob", last_name: "Smith", created_at: "2019-04-09 08:54:30", updated_at: "2019-04-09 08:54:30">
```

But then, the time is rendered as JST if I specifically ask for the `created_at` time:

```rb
User.first.created_at
#=> Tue, 09 Apr 2019 17:54:30 JST +09:00
```

Why are the timestamps being rendered as UTC unless I specifically ask for the time itself? Is this normal? The same phenomenon is happening for `DateTime` columns in my other tables as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your dates seems to be the same, it's just how they are represented on different contexts.

This:

```
User.first
#=> #<User id: 1, first_name: "Bob", last_name: "Smith", created_at: "2019-04-09 08:54:30", updated_at: "2019-04-09 08:54:30">
```

renders the result of `.inspect`

This:

```
User.first.created_at
#=> Tue, 09 Apr 2019 17:54:30 JST +09:00
```

is the console guessing you want the date formated with the current time zone.

You could force some representation being explicit

```
User.first.created_at.to_formatted_s(:db) #should print the same as you see on the inspect
I18n.localize(User.first.created_at) #should localize the date with the default date format
I18n.localize(USer.first.created_at, format: :something) #should localize the date as the format you defined as ":something" on your locale file
```

Comment: That was my point exactly - I was wondering why the timestamp was being rendered as UTC in some cases and JST in others (the time itself was the same). Does my configuration suffice to 1. save data in DB as UTC, but 2. render as JST in Rails?

Comment: @Risa as I understand from the output of your code, yes, your database has UTC dates and rails, by default, uses your time zone. Always remember to use the `localize` (or just `l`) helper to display dates with proper format and localization.